# Why would "Bareface" be mistaken for a Western?

Tags: title, c-s-lewis, genre, till-we-have-faces

From the Wikipedia page on C.S. Lewis's [*Till We Have Faces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Till_We_Have_Faces):

> C. S. Lewis originally titled his working manuscripts "Bareface". The editor (Gibb) rejected the title "Bareface" on the ground that readers would mistake it for a Western. In response, Lewis said he failed to see why people would be deterred from buying the book if they thought it was a Western, and that the working title was cryptic enough to be intriguing.

Firstly, what is meant by "Western" here? Does it refer to the [genre of Westerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_(genre)) set in the Old West of the United States? If so, then why would the title "Bareface" automatically lead readers to expect a Western novel?

Comment: Perhaps by association with [*The Paleface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paleface_(1948_film)), a popular 1948 Western movie.

Comment: As an indication of the 50s mania for Western fiction, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_comics lists 20+ Western comics being published (in the US, I assume) around 1957.  Only one of these seem to have survived beyond the early 70s.

Comment: I don't think we can definitely state why one publisher from sixty years ago thought something.